# Laptop not resuming from suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell, intel-graphics

I have a dell laptop that I installed Ubuntu on and I consistently get an issue where the screen doesn't come back on, it does sound like the fans are spinning back up though.

It is a dell 7352 with intel graphics card (Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)), 8GB of Ram and core i7 processor 5500U.  Running Ubuntu 20.04LTS

If I run swapon -s I get this back:

```
    Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        17825788    0   -2
/dev/dm-1                               partition   1003516 0   -3
```

I ran lspci to confirm the graphics card:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 5500
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

I checked syslog for error and found a few things that may be indicative of a problem but can't make heads or tails of it:

```
sysfs write failed /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/enabled 
ubuntu failed to load module dmraid: lib bd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECRD], AE_NOT_FOUND
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edited with info requested, sorry for the delay:
free -h gives me:

```
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.5Gi       3.2Gi       517Mi       2.0Gi       4.4Gi
Swap:          17Gi          0B        17Gi
```

running grep -i swap /etc/fstab gave me:

```
    /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

running: sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

```
A13
```

EDIT 8/31: I did some experiments that I reference in the comment below. The issue only appears when I manually put the laptop into suspend. If I allow it idle into suspend it resumes fine. Again any help is appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`, and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: In looking up the BIOS at Dell, I don't find a dell 7532. Can you please double-check that this is the correct model #? I also see two swaps, and 17G total swap. Why so much? Why two? Edit your question and show me `swapon -s`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, swapon -s is the top code bracket. The 17G total swap was that I read that you need twice the amount of ram if you want to do hibernation in your swap file.
The full model number and stuff from the receipt is this:
 Dell 2in1 13334 TouchScreen Laptop Intel Core i7 8GB Memory 1TB Hard Drive Silver Touch
  Model:  I7352-4445SLV
  SKU:  9514008

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you actually hibernate, or just sleep? You made the mods required to hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Dell I7352-4445SLV

You have BIOS version A13, from 9/26/2019.

There's a newer BIOS available, version A14, dated 7/14/2020, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-13-7352-laptop/drivers).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Swap**

You currently have 17G of swap spread out over two locations. ~1G on a disk partition, and ~17G in a /swapfile. That's unnecessarily large.

`sudo swapoff -a` # turn off swaps

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` # edit this file

Comment out this line to disable disk partition swap:

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Let's create a 4G /swapfile:

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

<strike>sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap</strike>

```
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

`swapon -s` should look similar to this:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        4194300    0   -2
```

Retest sleep/resume.

Comment: I was able to successfully update the bios A14 I also resized the swapfile to 8G. I tried to do a suspend and still encountered the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @deadpool631Good job on the BIOS update. You got a little ahead of me on the swap thing. Let me finish my thoughts on the swap part of my answer... check back in a few minutes, and then follow the instructions. Report back.

Comment: @heynema
Thanks for the suggestions unfortunately they didn't work. For reference this is what I get for  swapon -s *Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/swapfile                               file     4194300 0 -2
* when I do ls -al on the swapfile itself it gives me this: *-rw------- 1 root root 4294967296 Aug 30 16:44 /swapfile*
I don't know if this helpful information or not but I have noticed then when it doesn't resume correctly from sleep the next reboot it fails to recognize my microphone and headphone jack. But after a proper shutdown and restart it picks it up correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @deadpool631 Gosh. I really thought that would fix it. I'm stretching for ideas, and there aren't many, but you can go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: @heynema thanks for the input. I tried the memtest and it came back all fine. I do want to point something somewhat interesting that I have noticed. If I let the computer idle into suspend, it comes back fine. It's only when I try to manually suspend it seems to be a problem. I have tested this 4 times now and have successfully resumed from suspend every time. So I'm not sure what to make of that one.

Comment: @deadpool631 Good job on memtest. Good observation on idle suspect vs manual suspend. I'm sure it's a clue, but I'm out of ideas now. Sorry.